# OpenVPN - Connect external users to VirtualBox Internal Network

Tags: networking, openvpn, virtualbox

[Demo of connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfeEt.png)

I'm trying to set up a network where external users can use an ovpn file to connect to the "team1" internal network that I created in VirtualBox. The goal is to allow these users to only see devices within the internal network, but nowhere else. In fact, the ultimate goal would be for them to not even see the OpenVPN server, but that's secondary to establishing reliable connectivity.

So far, I have used [This script](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install) to built my openvpn files, and I can connect to the server, but openvpn assigns a 10.8.0.0/24 IP to the client and the client cannot access any devices on the network. In fact, it doesn't see network devices on either side of the openvpn server. For example, I have a home media server at 10.0.0.10, and pings/connection attempts to it fail, as well as attempts to connect to the "Target Box" at 10.10.10.101.

In hindsight, I should not have used such similar IP blocks, but I want to stick with the 10.10/16 for the internal network so that users connecting aren't having to differentiate between their own home network IP space and the IP space of this virtual network.

So, the end goal is:

- External user gets an ovpn file from me, uses it to connect to my IP (67.3.2.111).
- My home router forwards this connect to internal IP for the OpenVPN Server VM (10.0.1.100).
- The OpenVPN Server accepts the connection attempts and assigns the user an IP in the VBox internal network space (10.10.10.200-250).
- The user can only see devices in the VBox internal network space.

Comment: Have you edited the script that you used to use your desired IP ranges? It doesn't seem to me from what you wrote that you have but I felt it best to check!

Comment: @neildeadman yes, I edited the script where needed. The VPN-assigned IPs (10.8.0.0/24) aren't relevant to the connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

The VPN server must be configured as a router, that's to say, in a way that allows it forwarding network packages. If the server is Linux, to allow temporary forwarding packages, you should execute:

> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

To make changes permanent (more precisely, make the configuration be active when the process sysctl restarts), edit /etc/sysctl.conf and configure:

> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

You should also check that iptables rules allow network packets forwarding

> iptables -L

If there are rules that avoid forwarding, you should reconfigure iptables with a command like this one:

> iptables -A FORWARD <you could restrict the inputs here with -i> -j ACCEPT